# Is there a LINQ-provider for GeoDatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase

I want to query my ArcSDE geodatabase using LINQ but I don´t know if there is an ESRI-provider that may also read geometries and which is able to handle archiving as well. Thus I´d like to read data from a FeatureClass for example and apply a whereclause:

```
IRelationalOperator relOp = (IRelationalOperator) myFeature.Shape;
var features = featureClass
    .Where(x => relOp.Within(x.Shape) && x.MyProperty > 1)
    .OrderBy(x => x.MyProperty)
```

Appaerently while querying simple structures such as a numeric field might be quite easy I suppose geometric queries expect much more work.

Does this even exist or has anyone ever done something similar? Will it exist on ArcGIS Pro (of course not using arcobjects)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really think ESRI does not provide a LINQ-provider for GeoDatabases, even if that would be cool. I remember some discussions in ESRI forums time ago about people encouraging such improvement.
The unique way I guess is to:

1. Implement that by yourself, I mean, creating a extension method for the `FeatureClass` object. That could be very crazy stuff!!
2. [Access SQL Server directly via Linq to SQL, once it supports spatial types.](https://ambergis.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/linq-to-geodatabase-provider/) But I am not sure about how you could handle the relational operators.

PS1: I would use a `ISpatialFilter` and `IQueryFilter` but let me know if you find something else =)
PS2: Forget about a specific implementation in ArcGIS Pro. That will not occur in the short time.

Comment: Seems to be the (unsatisfying) answer, thanks however. Maybe it´s worth the effort on posting via GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to recommend using bits of this library as it is a headstart on what Katah was describing with extension methods and feature classes:
https://github.com/esride-apf/Linq2ArcObjects

I don't see support just yet for ISpatialFilter, but I think you could branch this code and edit "src/FeatureClassExtensions.cs" and add your spatial filtering.

A seemingly solid library of esri linq/feature class extensions is Jumpercables/Wave @ Github here: https://github.com/Jumpercables/Wave/tree/7b44df2fd4ebd0c581fc6b3926f63a35ea4f482d/src/Wave.Extensions.Esri/ESRI/ArcGIS.

Hope that helps!